# Initialize a 200 by 785 numpy matrix with values from a Gaussian distribution with mean 0, std. deviation 0.01

Tags: python, numpy

In python, how do I initialize/create such a matrix? (Initialize a 200 by 785 numpy matrix with values from a Gaussian distribution with mean 0, std. deviation 0.01)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`numpy.random`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.normal.html#numpy.random.normal)

```
>>> sample = numpy.random.normal(0, 0.01, (200, 785))
```

Checking the sample to see it makes sense:

```
>>> sample.mean()
2.4189183974354331e-05
>>> sample.std()
0.010016252682198676
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Dead link. Working one - https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.random.normal.html#numpy.random.normal